# Would not Wallace have understood that K would have valuable information?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

It is unclear to me why K was so badly treated by Luv -- she at one point mutters, "Do your fucking job..." while watching him remotely -- surely K could know and in fact does possess information about Ana that even Deckard does not have. So why not at try to win K over or at least torture it out of him?

Answer (score 1):

Don't read too much into Luv's comment. In the moment you mention, she's swearing at K in precisely the same way an angry motorist swears at their car when it refuses to start: out of frustration and not a tiny bit of fear that the object of scorn is too broken to continue.

So, why doesn't Wallace try to get info out of K? Because Wallace has his hands on Deckard, who *definitely* knows more about the child than K.

The movie ends before we see how Wallace learns that Deckard has escaped (and Luv killed), so, for all we know, his next move *would* have been to try capture and interrogate K. (And I think the movie makes it clear that would be impossible.)

Comment: There's no indication that Wallace knows _anything_ about K to begin with. Luv is secretive and crafty.